# Trouble with exec command on mariadb container

Tags: docker, mariadb

I want to access the db directly through command prompt.

I run the command:

```
docker exec -it container_name -u user_name -p
```

Instead of a line asking me the user password I get the following error message:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-u\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

I've tried several other commands of the same type:

```
docker exec -it container_name -u -p
docker exec -it container_name -u user_name 
docker exec -it container_name -u root
```

I don't use a Dockerfile but the image directly :

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
      build: ./frontend
      volumes:
          - ./frontend/:/app
      ports:
          - ${PORT_FRONTEND}:${PORT_FRONTEND}
      container_name: dev_frontend
  database:
      image: mariadb
      environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
          - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
          - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=${ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD}
      ports:
          - "${PORT_MARIADB}:${PORT_MARIADB}"
      volumes:
          - ./volumes/database/:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      container_name: dev_mariadb
```

I use a .env file to store sensible data instead of placing them in the docker-compose.yml

If anyone has any idea on how to proceed to find the issue I'd be grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply correct the command above with :

```
docker exec -it container_name mysql -u{username} -p{userpassword}
```